Handle 'select' or 'click' event on vgform:Select
I have been using Vugu to build an internal dashboard, however I can't see how to register an event listener for a change/click/select event on a select dropdown box.
For example:
<vgform:Select class="form-control"
       :Value='vgform.StringPtrDefault(&c.clientId, c.defaultClientId())'  
       :Options='c.clientOptions.Title()'>  
</vgform:Select>

I have tried various incantations (@click, @select, @change, @onchange, @onclick, @onselect, @mouseup, ...) and looked through the vugu library code itself but can't find an example of how to do this.
What is the recommended approach?
<vgform:Select class="form-control"
       :Value='vgform.StringPtrDefault(&c.clientId, c.defaultClientId())'  
       :Options='c.clientOptions.Title()'
       @select="c.handleClientChanged()'>  <--- DOESN'T WORK
</vgform:Select>

